# C# MVC razor page foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been using stackoverflow for a long time, just never asked a question, but I need some advice now and can't seem to find the answer!

My question is, how do I pass the ClassId from my instructor model to match the ClassId in my class model. In other words, when I click on “view roster” I want to only see the students in that particular class? I hope that makes sense. For example, teacher would log in, view all classes he/she is teaching, and be able to view roster for each class identified by classID.

I am not using Entity Frameworks. Just displaying data from a stored procedure running on MSSQL. I think a razor page view is what I am after? [Here is what I have so far for an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WPqX.png)  Thank you in advance!!!

Here is my ClassModel:

```
     public class ClassModel
  { 
     [Display(Name = "SID")]
     public int SID { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Name")]
     public string FullName { get; set; }


     public int ClassID { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my InstructorModel

```
   public class InstructorModel
{
    [Display(Name= "Course Title")]
    public string CourseTitle{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Class ID")]
    public int ClassID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Room")]
    public string Room { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }


    public int InstructorSID { get; set; }


}
```

InstructorController

```
  public class InstructorController : Controller
{

    // GET: Course Details

    DAL.DB dblayer = new DAL.DB();
    public ActionResult Index(InstructorModel InstructorModel)

    {
        DataSet ds = dblayer.GetInstructor(InstructorModel.InstructorSID); 
        ViewBag.general = ds.Tables[0];


        return View();
    }
}
```

ClassController

```
  public class ClassController : Controller
{

    // GET: Students in Class

    DAL.DB dblayer = new DAL.DB();
    public ActionResult Index(ClassModel ClassModel)

    {
        DataSet ds1 = dblayer.GetClass(ClassModel.ClassID);
        ViewBag.general = ds1.Tables[0];

        return View();
    }
}
```

and my View

```
 @model IEnumerable<ABEAttendanceV3.Models.InstructorModel>
 <div class="table-responsive">
<table id="tablereport" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead style="background-color:black; font-weight:bold; color:aliceblue">
        <tr>

    </thead>

    <thead style="background-color:black; font-weight:bold; color:aliceblue">
        <tr>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Class ID</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.general.Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@dr["CourseTitle"]</td>
                    <td>@dr["ClassID"]</td>
                    <td>@dr["Room"]</td>
                    <td>@dr["StartTime"]</td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("View Roster", "Class", new { id = ViewBag.ClassID})
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Sorry! My question is, how do I pass the ClassId from my instructor model to match the  ClassId in my class model. In other words, when I click on “view roster” I want to only see the students in that particular class? I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing ClassModel pass a querystring of ClassId and get that Classid and do what you want so your code will modified like :

```
@{
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.general.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@dr["CourseTitle"]</td>
                <td>@dr["ClassID"]</td>
                <td>@dr["Room"]</td>
                <td>@dr["StartTime"]</td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("View Roster", "Class", new { id = dr["ClassId"]})
                </td>

            </tr>
        }

    }
```

And in your controller inside View Roster ActionMethod Just do

```
   public ActionResult ThankYou(string ClassId) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Class", new { id = ClassId });

}
```

Then on the Class Controller:

```
DAL.DB dblayer = new DAL.DB();
public ActionResult Index(string id)

{
    DataSet ds1 = dblayer.GetClass(id);
    ViewBag.general = ds1.Tables[0];

    return View();
}
```

Hope this make some sense